# How to call a Thread in a method

Tags: java, multithreading, methods

I want to programmatically move a `Thread` in another method. How I can do this?

Comment: You cannot.  It is not possible to call threads, only signal them.

Comment: @Martina James And what I do for signal them?

Comment: You need to explain in detail what you are really trying to do here, because your one sentence statement makes little sense.

Comment: I want to call a Thread in a specific method: `public void rispostaComando(){ /*Calling Thread...*/ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's entirely not possible in Java. 
There are some ways around that - using tools like AtomicReferences, AtomicBoolean, wait/notify or Channels. With these tools, you could inform the other thread that it should do something specific.

Another approach would be to copy SwingUtilities invokeLater - like here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

However, I would like to ask the question why that method execution needs to be run in a specific thread? Wouldn't just another (new thread) be fine too? That should significally simplify your problem. In that case, just start a new thread to call that method